# insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: apt, kde, lightdm, sddm

osinfo :

```
cat /etc/*-release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
DISTRIB_ID=neon
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="KDE neon User Edition 5.10"
NAME="KDE neon"
VERSION="5.10"
ID=neon
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="KDE neon User Edition 5.10"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://neon.kde.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://neon.kde.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kde.org/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

My problem : when i do apt-get update or install or whatever, i get the same thing (maybe slightly different). I suspect it has something to do with lightdm or sddm (i don't really know what they do). So i tried to purge and reinstall them. I'm afraid i made it a bit worse, but not too bad (since everything else on the os still seems to be working).
I wasn't fooling around with anything when this first occurred.

Error :

```
[sudo] password for alex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Entering ResolveByKeep 50%
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  flashplugin-installer
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6.834 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 flashplugin-installer amd64 26.0.0.131ubuntu0.16.04.1 [6.834 B]
Fetched 6.834 B in 0s (39,0 kB/s)                
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 191730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../flashplugin-installer_26.0.0.131ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (26.0.0.131ubuntu0.16.04.1) over (26.0.0.126ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.4) ...
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20170616.1.orig.tar.gz
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20170616.1.orig.tar.gz [30,4 MB]
Fetched 30,4 MB in 8s (3.494 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20170616.1.orig.tar.gz' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Installing from local file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20170616.1.orig.tar.gz
Flash Plugin installed.
Setting up lightdm (1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-bin:
 grub-efi-amd64-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64:
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub2-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi-amd64 depends on grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
 grub-efi depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.11); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cgmanager (0.39-2ubuntu5) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cgmanager (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up ebtables (2.0.10.4-3.4ubuntu2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ebtables (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libvirt-bin:
 libvirt-bin depends on cgmanager | cgroup-lite | cgroup-bin; however:
  Package cgmanager is not configured yet.
  Package cgroup-lite is not installed.
  Package cgroup-bin is not installed.
 libvirt-bin depends on ebtables; however:
  Package ebtables is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libvirt-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of os-prober:
 os-prober depends on grub-common; however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package os-prober (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up sddm (0.14.0-1~2.gbpf70012+16.04+xenial+build8) ...
dpkg: error processing package sddm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 1
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service smfpd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service smfpd if started
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up flashplugin-installer (26.0.0.131ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-efi-amd64-bin
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi
 cgmanager
 ebtables
 libvirt-bin
 os-prober
 sddm
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

note : i deleted a few : nsserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
 lines so the questions wouldn't be too big.

How would i best go about fixing this?

Comment: I suspect it's related to 3rd party (Samsung) printer drivers - see this similar askubuntu Q&A: [16.04 LTS Update fails - Errors were encountered while processing util-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881218/16-04-lts-update-fails-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-util-linux/884130)

Comment: I do not know how you found it, because i searched and didn't find that answer. I don't know how to upvote, but if i could i would.

Comment: I guess my google-fu was just stronger - it might be worth editing your title so that it refers to "insserv: warning: script 'K07smfpd' missing LSB tags and overrides" to make your Q&A easier for others to find in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) and his comment i could read this question on Ask Ubuntu: [16.04 LTS Update fails - Errors were encountered while processing util-linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881218/16-04-lts-update-fails-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-util-linux/884130).
I don't have a samsung printer/driver but it did get me to try to uninstall my dell printer driver.

To uninstall :

```
cd /opt/DELL/mfp/uninstall
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```

Doing this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the same issue is caused by other printers as well.

Run `uninstall.sh` in `/opt/<Printer Vendor>/mfp/uninstall`.

I had a Xerox printer installed some time ago, and not currently using it. Removing the driver made the updates working.

Answer (score 1):

I use panasonic printer.

I edit the file panasoniclpd-init:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/panasoniclpd-init
```

Add this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
Provides:          panasoniclpd-init
Required-Start:    $all
Required-Stop:     $all
Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
Default-Stop:      0 1 6
Short-Description: Panasonic MFS driver for MB20xx
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: ### BEGIN INIT INFO [/p]
# Provides:          panasoniclpd-init
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Panasonic MFS driver for MB20xx
### END INIT INFO